forward from azure private resolver to public external
I have a scenario where I need all dns requests not handled by azure dns to be forwarded to public external dns resolvers for security reasons. There is an allow list for which ips can access this service but as far as I can tell private resolver outbound endpoints don't have a dedicated public ip address that's exposed to me.
2 questions
can I create an outbound catch all rule with . that'd be honored last? Meaning I could at least forward.
do I need another resolver between the private resolver service and the external resolver with a pip? Since by definition it's a "private" resolver I'm assuming I can't access a pip for it. The forward look ups would look like this, where I'm not sure if I need the internal resolver in italics
vnet -> fw proxy -> private resolver service (outbound rule) -> internal resolver with pip -> external resolver
